# Product meta data from order id WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Attempting to pull product data from the last order such as `[key] => pa_size`

Using `automatewoo_update_print_file` to call file.php where the two function is located, it's called when a new note is added to an order:

```
 function automatewoo_update_print_file( $workflow ) {

 include '/home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***-child/woocommerce/checkout/file.php'; 


}
```

**Update** This worked well to pull the most recent order ID and get the product id, then the meta data from the ID and also the rest of the order data. But I still need to pull `[key] => pa_size`

```
function get_last_order_id(){
global $wpdb;
$statuses = array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses());
$statuses = implode( "','", $statuses );

// Getting last Order ID (max value)
$results = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
    WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND post_status IN ('$statuses')
" );
return reset($results);
}

$latest_order_id = get_last_order_id(); // Last order ID
$order = wc_get_order( $latest_order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order oject
$order_details = $order->get_data(); // Get the order data in an array
$order_status = $order_details['status'];


foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ):
$product_id   = $item->get_product_id();
$variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
$item_name    = $item->get_name(); // Name of the product
$quantity     = $item->get_quantity();  

$product        = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object

$product_price  = $product->get_price();

endforeach;

$print_file = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'print_file_url', true );

// Raw output for testing
echo 'Product Price<pre> '; print_r( $product_price ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Product Name<pre> '; print_r( $item_name ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Product Quantity<pre> '; print_r( $quantity ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Product ID<pre> '; print_r( $product_id ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Variation ID<pre> '; print_r( $variation_id ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Print File Url<pre> '; print_r( $print_file ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Order Status<pre>'; print_r( $order_status ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Latest Order ID<pre>'; print_r( $latest_order_id ); echo '</pre>';
echo 'Order Details<pre>'; print_r( $order_details ); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: _“but need to take it a step further”_ - well then do so …? (Or, ask an _actual_ question - see [ask].)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function for get last order id

```
$last_order_id = wc_get_customer_last_order($user_id);
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->get_items();
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ){
    // Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
    $item_id = $item->get_id();
    ## Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods ##
    $product      = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object
    $product_id   = $item->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id(); // the Variation id
    $item_type    = $item->get_type(); // Type of the order item ("line_item")
    $item_name    = $item->get_name(); // Name of the product
    $quantity     = $item->get_quantity();  
    $tax_class    = $item->get_tax_class();
    $line_subtotal     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Line subtotal (non discounted)
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Line subtotal tax (non discounted)
    $line_total        = $item->get_total(); // Line total (discounted)
    $line_total_tax    = $item->get_total_tax(); // Line total tax (discounted)
    $product        = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object
    $product_type   = $product->get_type();
    $product_sku    = $product->get_sku();
    $product_price  = $product->get_price();
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
}
```

Try this

```
function get_names( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if (empty($order)) return false;
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $item_name    = $item->get_name();
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. The order id is already successfully returned to `$latest_order_id` but need to get the product meta for the first product. I posted an updated attempt to get the first product name with no luck, ideally `print_file_url` is the product meta field I'm trying to receive.

Comment: Thank you for the update, unfortunately I was unable to get either function to work. All that was returned was a blank value. I have updated the question to show how this is been called from `include '../checkout/file.php';` I'm only able to access the order_id through the original function I provided assuming it is because it is querying the database directly?